# Strange canvas issue

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm facing a really strange problem with canvas tag.
Depending on the size, the drawing fails.
This really basic code works, but if I set the height to 165, the drawing fails.
Thanks for the help.

```
<canvas id="screen" width="400" height="164" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
        Incompatible navigator
</canvas>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    window.onload = function () {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("screen");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var width = canvas.width;
        var height = canvas.height;
        var screen = {
                width: canvas.width,
                height: canvas.height,
                clear: function (ctx) {
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF00FF";
                    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
                }
        };
        screen.clear(ctx);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Please post an console errors to help us debug

Comment: What do you by *fails*? Any errors?

Comment: [It works for me.](http://jsfiddle.net/fhunsn6x/)

Comment: it is the size of what? what fails? what is your definition of a failure? it is hard to find a black cat in a dark room, especially if there is no cat.

Comment: I was able to set the height to 165 and run successfully. I am runnning on firefox.

Comment: It works for me too. I tried heights greater and less than 165 (tested Chrome, Firefox, and IE8)

Comment: I have no error output. The drawing just fails :/

Comment: Ok, I absolutely don't know why, but it works on firefox but not on chrome. Thank you all.

Comment: @kevincoulibaly that fiddle works on Chrome for me.

Comment: Also working in Chrome for me. There's nothing technically special about a height of 165, and no reason it would not work.